# Difference between before and after in viewDidLoad

Tags: swift, core-data, uisearchcontroller, viewdidload

I have tried to set the `searchBar` as a `tableHeaderView` inside of the `viewDidLoad`:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    // SearchController initializiation
    self.searchController = UISearchController.init(searchResultsController: nil)
    self.searchController.delegate = self
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    self.searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    self.searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
    self.searchController.searchBar.keyboardAppearance = .default
    self.searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true
    self.searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false


    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar
    self.definesPresentationContext = true

    self.fetch()
    self.tableView.reloadData()

}
```

And this my `fetch()` function:

```
func fetch() {
    let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<Phone> = Phone.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor.init(key: "header", ascending: true), NSSortDescriptor.init(key: "date", ascending: true)]

    self.fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController.init(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: "header", cacheName: nil)
    self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

    do {
        try self.fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    } catch {}

}
```

But I don't understand they are doesn't work. The Xcode crashes and nothing actually happens. And then I have tried to change something inside of `viewDidLoad` method:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.fetch()
    self.tableView.reloadData()

    // SearchController initializiation
    self.searchController = UISearchController.init(searchResultsController: nil)
    self.searchController.delegate = self
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    self.searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    self.searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
    self.searchController.searchBar.keyboardAppearance = .default
    self.searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true
    self.searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false


    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar
    self.definesPresentationContext = true



}
```

Success! Works properly. I don't understand what is the difference?

Comment: What's the error message when it crashes? What is the exact line that it crashes on? Please share the stack trace.

Comment: Nothing! In the console only (lldb)

Comment: Is there any info in the console? There's not enough info in your question to solve your issue.

Comment: Do you do anything in the delegate methods of the UISearchController that assume that the `fetchedResultsController` is not nil?

Comment: @JonRose Did you mean the UISearchResultsUpdating protocol?

Comment: yes. I meant both `UISearchResultsUpdating` and `UISearchBarDelegate`.  The viewController is being set as delegate for two different objects (`searchBar.delegate` and `searchResultsUpdater`) before the fetchedResultsController is setup.  So it can get methods called by them immediately.  If those methods assume that there is a fetchedResultsController setup it could cause a logical error.

Answer (score 2):

You should try removing the `self.tableView.reloadData()` from the `viewDidLoad()` method, because the data wasn't even loaded to be reloaded.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you set the delegates for searchResultsUpdater and searchBar before even your fetchedResultsController is initialised. Some where in your code searchResultsUpdater or searchBar's delegate methods are accessing your fetchedResultsController and getting it nil so you app crashes. My suggestion is to avoid the crash is to make searchResultsController as computed or lazy property.